# Zabbix Preprocessing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, zabbix

I have a value variable VALUE it is a literal numeric task to display 1 if the value is literal numeric and 0 if the value is FAILED
Please tell me who knows what JS will look like, a beginner in programming.

function (value)
{
return value
}

Comment: It looks like some of your code is missing. Please [edit] the question to add it

Comment: unfortunately this is all that is from the existing code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript code will be like this:

```js
function checkValue(value) {
  var result;
  if (!isNaN(value) && value !== '') {
    result = "1";
  } else if (value === "FAILED") {
    result = "0";
  } else {
    result = "value is not a literal numeric value or is FAILED.";
  }
  return result;
}
```

As a Zabbix javascript preprocessing:

[image: zabbix javascript preprocessing]

Test:

[image: test in zabbix of the above code]